# Switching roles of EDI and ESI registers

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

Can roles of EDI and ESI be switched?

For example, can EDI contain pointer to array and we only print it out every value/character in array?

Comment: Usually it's easier to switch values in registers, than modifying rest of code. If you ever happen to be in a situation where you need `esi`/`edi` just in the other one, then `xchg esi,edi` will resolve that. It's not exactly fast instruction, so usually you avoid that by planning register usage of code ahead, and write the remaining code to work without additional `xchg/mov` instructions, keeping intermediate results directly in registers which will be picked up by next code... when possible... when not, use `xchg` or additional `mov`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't switch the roles of (R|E)SI and (R|E)DI for the string instructions, such as MOVSB. The source and destination registers are implied by the instructions themselves, and essentially hardcoded.

Everywhere else, you can adjust your code appropriately to use one register instead of another.